# How can I get IceCast stream metadata in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, streaming, metadata, icecast

I have created an HTML5 web page that uses HtmlAudioElement to play an IceCast audio stream.

I would like to display Artist/Song information, which is sent as Metadata within the IceCast stream.

Can I get that information from the stream using HTML5/JavaScript?

Comment: THere's a stream type I've not heard of for a Loooong Time :-)   and to be perfectly honest, I didn't even think it was still on the go.  However, before I can even attempt to answer your question, I'd like to see your code and how your grabbing the stream, so I can see if there are any hooks you might be able to exploit.